# Transparent background in Asymptote animation

Tags: asymptote, animate

In my TeX distribution there are two Asymptote examples named `inlinemovie.tex` and `inlinemovie3.tex`. (They are also [available here](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/animations/).)

## Quick question

The two animations in `inlinemovie.tex` have transparent backgrounds while the animation in `inlinemovie3.tex` has its background opaquely white. You can verify this by adding `\vspace*{-3cm}` between `\end{verbatim}` and `begin{center}` in both files.

I want the later transparent as well.

transparent background:

[image]

opaque background:

[image]

## Explanation

I have been trying understanding animations in TeX world for days. While Ti*k*Z is extremely awesome, I found Asymptote irreplaceable due to its ability to render 3D objects.

However, Asymptote is ill-documented (in English). Turns out I need following commands to compile `inlinemovie.tex`, say, completely:

1. `pdflatex inlinemovie.tex`: creates `inlinemovie-1.asy` and `inlinemovie-2.asy`
2. `asy inlinemovie-*.asy`: compiles `-1.asy` and `-2.asy` and creates junks...
3. `pdflatex inlinemovie.tex`: includes images from the previous step.
4. `pdflatex inlinemovie.tex`: for safety.

The problem begins from step 2. If you pass `asy inlinemovie-* -keep` instead, you would see that Asymptote creates files such as `_movie1_9.pdf`, `_movie1.pdf`, `_movie2_9.pdf`, `_movie2.pdf`, `_movie1_9.eps`, and `_movie2_9.eps`. It is hard to tell what is the logic behind these filenames.

Everything will be fine if the final results are of transparent background. However, when I compiled `inlinemovie3.tex`, I found the picture `_movie3+9.pdf` is of opaque background. So everything after it would have opaque background too I guess.

I know from experience that the PNG outputs <del>are always of</del> **may have, through external programs,** transparent background, no matter it is 2D or 3D. So the problem is in the animation part. **Can I make the intermediate files to be PNGs so I can transparentize them then?** I tried to check `animation.asy` and `animate.sty` but I cannot tell what exactly generates `_movie3+9.pdf` <del>and what contributes to its background</del>.

---

P.S. I made a stupid mistake so stupid that I need to edit my post, knowing that this will raise my post to the top of the list.

After O.G.'s comment I checked my old, transparent, 3D PNGs and tried to recompile some of them. Surprisingly I found that I actually had written an additional script to generate transparent version and replace old files with the same filenames --- I just forgot my efforts and regarded them as defaults.

This script still works today. So the only issue is to insert a *transparentizing* step. Even more precisely, may someone locate the line that generates `_movie3+9.pdf` and tell me if it is possible to call external scripts (probably something involving ImageMagick) in Asymptote, I would like do the remaining job.

Comment: The transparent background seems to be not available in 3D rendered picture. It is not related to animation, a (static) 3D picture does not have a transparent background even in png format. For one picture it is possible using convert (see https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/0cfb1491). Perhaps that the following code (a background for a logo) can also help https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/1694f7fc

Comment: It is possible to `convert` ... for one picture? Cannot I `convert` multiple pictures as long as I modify the animation pipeline? So the remaining thing is to dig into these intermediate files.

Comment: Your experience seems to be mistaken: 3d outputs always have opaque background in any file format unless `settings.render = 0;`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats yes... I just found that I actually wrote an additional script to make those PNG transparent. It is indeed an old experience. I messed everything up.

Comment: @O.G. sourceforge is still down... But you are right that it require more effort to make it transparent. But animation part is still the problem even though I know what I want now.