# how to have transparent background in 3d plot of asymptote?

Tags: 3d, asymptote

how to have transparent background in 3d plot of asymptote? Any idea? Suppose we save the output in png format, we can have transparent background in 2d plot of asymptote using the following,

```
      currentlight.background=opacity(0.0)+rgb(255,255,255);
```

But it doesn't work in the 3d. How to do this in 3d plot of asymptote?

Comment: Even though this post (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255614) asks about animations, I think some of the comments might help you.

Comment: At the moment, I don't think this can be done (unless you set `settings.render = 0`, which comes with its own set of issues).

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. I found a compromise now. Since I try to remove the white background in my plot to be compatible with the background of the template, I used currentlight.background to change the background of my 3d plot and make it the same as that in the template. Except transparent background, it works very well for other color.